# Is $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\big(\sum\limits_{d|3^x-1}{1/d}\big)/\big(\sum\limits_{p<x}1/p\big)<\infty$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Can anyone provide any suggestion if the following is true for natural number $x$?
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{d|3^x-1}{\frac{1}{d}}}{\sum\limits_{p<x}\dfrac{1}{p}}<\infty$$ where $p$ runs over primes.

**P.S** I know that
the bound ${\sum\limits_{d|n}{\frac{1}{d}}}<e^{\gamma}\log\log n +O(1)$is true so maybe it could help.

Comment: (Using Sage, checking for $x<180$) The given fraction seems to always be in $[3/4,3]$, with no obvious tendency. For $x$ prime, it seems to decrease and is $<0.8$ for $x\ge 149$, while for (apparently) most other values it's $\ge 1$, with apparent jumps (e.g., $x=160$ yields $1.58...$).

Comment: BTW liminf should be zero: for $x$ prime, one would expect the sum in the numerator to be $1+(1/2)+o(1)$ (maybe easy), so the fraction would be $\sim 3/2\log\log x\to 0$.

Comment: Your upper bound already shows a $\preceq \log x / \log\log x$ bound. So a slow partial convergence to infinity would not be much visible from such a small range as above.

Comment: The inequality in your "P.S." is Robin's criterion for the Riemann Hypothesis. So we don't know that it is true, we only expect (hope, conjecture etc.) that it is true.

Comment: @GH from MO I did an error.I guess now with a big Oh it can be proven.

Comment: @Superguy: The inequality in your updated "P.S." is known indeed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The OP's first display is true. Indeed, [Erdős (1971)](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1971-14.pdf) proved that
$$\sum_{d\mid 2^x-1}\frac{1}{d}\ll\log\log x\ll\sum_{p<x}\frac{1}{p},$$
and he noted that the proof works equally well for the divisors of $a^x-1$.

Comment: You seem to write $f\ll g$ for $f=O(g)$. Is this standard? I always understood it as $f=o(g)$.

Comment: @YCor the Vinogradov notation $f(x) \ll g(x)$ is indeed the same as the Landau big O notation $f(x) = O(g(x))$ in analytic number theory.

Answer (score 4):

One remark for the OP. On certain well-believed conjectures, the exact value of the limsup can be determined. The answer involves $\gamma$, $\log 3$, and an integral expression with Dickman's rho function. See this arXiv paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.02373 (Theorem 1.2 and section 6)